# string maps and add in Coq

Tags: maps, addition, coq

In my proofs, I reached a goal looking similar to the following: (The actual types are different (zm : StringMap.string String.string, key and elt are String.string) ). In my code, if I have  `H: z1k <> z2k` in environment, then its easy by `intuition congruence` but if I dont have such an hypothesis, then I can't prove my goal. Moreover, I can't prove `v1 = v2` as well, which can help in proving the goal. Please if some one guide me solving such scenarios. Thanks,

```
Parameter t : Type -> Type.
Variable key : Type.
Variable elt : Type.
Implicit Type m: t elt.
Implicit Type x y z: key.
Implicit Type e: elt.

Require String.

Record id : Type :=
build_id {
         id_v : String.string;
         id_k: key
        }.

Parameter add : key -> elt -> t elt -> t elt.
Parameter MapsTo : key -> elt -> t elt -> Prop.

Lemma MyTest: forall v1 v2 (z1k z2k zk: key) (ze z1 z2: elt) zm, 
build_id v1 z1k <> build_id v2 z2k ->
MapsTo zk ze (add z1k z1 (add z2k z2 zm)) -> 
MapsTo zk ze (add z2k z2 (add z1k z1 zm)).
Proof.
```

Comment: What if `v1 <> v2` but `z1k = z2k`, and `z1 <> z2`? Also, could you list the theorems that hold for `add` and `MapsTo`?

Comment: I guess you have something like MapsTo k e (add u v s) -> MapsTo k e s \/ (k = u /\ e = v) ?

Comment: @Ptival  I have put a detailed version of the problem at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160579/solving-morphism-proper-functions-with-maps-in-coq)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to assume decidable equality on `key`? Then you might get further by case analysis on whether the record elements are pairwise equal or not. For example, using Adam Chlipala's CPDT tactic, I get this:

```
Add LoadPath "~/dev/cpdt/src".

Require String.    
Require Import CpdtTactics.

Variable key : Type.    

Record id : Type := build_id {    
  id_v : String.string;    
  id_k : key    
}.

Axiom key_dec : forall a b : key, {a = b} + {a <> b}.

Lemma unpack_build_id_ineq : forall a b x y, build_id a x <> build_id b y ->    
  (a <> b) \/ (x <> y).    
Proof.    
  intros.    
  set (H1 := String.string_dec a b).    
  set (H2 := key_dec x y).    
  crush.    
Qed.
```

In other words, given that the two records are unequal, there are two cases: either `id_v` or `id_k` components are unequal. Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I am rather a beginner in Coq, I hope you get more qualified help here, or you can also try the Coq Club mailing list.

Comment: To solve the goal, we require `id_k1 <> id_k2`, or `id_v1 = id_v2`. I tried what you suggested but I can not solve the case when `id_v1 <> id_v2`.

Comment: A detailed version of the problem is at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160579/solving-morphism-proper-functions-with-maps-in-coq). Thanks,